# Add ImageButton to ListView

Tags: java, android

Im trying to add an ImageButton to each row in my ListView (which I implemented via CustomAdapter). Each button should open a different WebView. I can't seem to find any tutorials to do this so any advice/tips/links would be highly apreciated.

EDIT 1:

My Listview XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_x="15dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/a"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/local"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/versus"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/resultsiz"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    android:textStyle="normal|bold"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/resultsde"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/resultsde"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/resultsde"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/resultsde"
    android:layout_marginRight="61dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="61dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/a"
    android:id="@+id/versus"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/visit"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/local"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/local" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/a"
    android:id="@+id/visit"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/resultsiz"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/versus"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/versus" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/local"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/local"
    android:id="@+id/dia"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/resultsde"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dia"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/local"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/local"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/local"
    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
    android:id="@+id/stats" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my CustomAdapter:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    lista.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultsizq.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout,null);





            ImageView versus = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.versus);
            ImageView local = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.local);
            ImageView visit = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.visit);

            TextView dia= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dia);
            TextView resultsiz= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.resultsiz);
            TextView resultsde= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.resultsde);



            dia.setText(di[position]);
            resultsiz.setText(resultsizq[position]);
            resultsde.setText(resultsder[position]);
            versus.setImageResource(versu[position]);
            local.setImageResource(loc[position]);
            visit.setImageResource(vis[position]);




            if ((position+1)%4==0){
                view.setPadding(0,0,0,150);

            }

            if ((position)%4==0){
                view.setPadding(0,150,0,0);

            }


            return view;
        }}
```

Comment: show us your listview item XML layout and your CustomAdapter. you're actually on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getView` method, you should assign the `onClick` function to the `Button` according to the given position. Probably, you should get the item located at `position`, generate some url based on the properties of this item, and let this url be opened in the `onClick` function.

More than that, I have 3 suggestions to improve your code:

1. Try to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.
2. Even if you use `ListView`, have a look at `View Holder` pattern. [This](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) is a good place to start.
3. Consider using `Butterknife`, [which](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) increases the readability of your code. If I were you, I would keep the item as a property in the view  holder object, which has a function annotated with `@OnClick(R.id.stats)` so that it opens the preferred `WebView` accordingly.

I hope these help.

Comment: Ok so basically use an onClick function and maybe use a for loop to create the corresponding url. Ok so say my url for button1 is www.example.com/hi1, for button2 it's www.example.com/hi2, etc. How could i change the last digit of the url? Maybe converting it to 2 strings and adding +1 each time? Im really new to programming sorry for so many questions.

Comment: @DavidGarciaBallester I don't know your case exactly but you should not need a for loop to generate the url. It should be something like, `Object item = getItem(position); String url = generateUrl(item); statsButton.setOnClick(...);` generateUrl is your function that generates the url for a given item.

Comment: Ok, finally did it with URi.It's working now. Thank you so much!